# Совмещение метода и события KeyDown

Tags: c#

Помогите совместить метод и событие `KeyDown`. Через "или"

```
private void Form5_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
  {
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.close();
    Player.controls.stop();
    f2.Show();
    this.Close();
  }
}

private void Player_PlayStateChange(int NewState)
{
  if ((WMPLib.WMPPlayState)NewState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped)
  {
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show();
    this.Hide();
    Player.controls.stop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Подход не верный. Но если бросать всё, как есть, то сделать отдельный метод в котором в зависимости от буловской переменной выполнять действия, в одном ивенте изменять буловскую на фэлс, в другом на тру...

Comment: `WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer Player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
    Player.PlayStateChange += new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(Player_PlayStateChange); axWindowsMediaPlayer1.close();
    Player.controls.stop();
    f2.Show();
    this.Close();` ?

Comment: Может быть при Keys.space делать WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer Player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer(); Player.PlayStateChange -= new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(Player_PlayStateChange); 
а соответственно при вашем ивенте убирать ивент кейдовна... Как вариант..(Внимание на "-=" убрал ивент). В конце выполненых действий перед this.close ивент возвращать

Comment: @xSx а мой способ работает?)

Comment: эм.. Не я создатель вопроса, не могу проверить. а я лично не понял в чем соль...